# como ejecutar diferentes funciones según el tamaño de pantalla

Tags: javascript, html, html5

tengo problema con un menu porque cuando esta reducido para tamaños de pantalla chicos le coloque una funcion en js para que al seleccionar la sección deseada se cierre autoamticamente para mejorar la UX.

html

```
<div id="cardMenu">
            <figure id="hideMenu" class="ioMenuMovil exit" onClick="displayMenu()"></figure>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li id="diseño"><a href="diseño_Grafico.html">DISEÑO GRAFICO</a></li>
                <li id="bolsas"><a href="bolsas_de_papel.html">BOLSAS IMPRESAS</a></li>
                <li id="carteleria"><a href="carteleria.html">CARTELERIA</a></li>
                <li id="cYE" onClick="displayCyE()"><a href="#">CUMPLES Y EVENTOS</a>
                    <ul id="subMenuCyE">
                        <li>Diseños personalizados de</li>
                        <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#souvenirs">SOUVENIRS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#tarjetas">TARJETAS </a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#pins">PINS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#banderines">BANDERINES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#mesas">MESAS DULCES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="cumples_y_eventos.html#bolcita">BOLCITAS PARA CARAMELOS</a></li>
                        <li><a class="ultimo" href="cumples_y_eventos.html#bolcita">CAJITAS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="otrosServicios" onClick="displayOs()"><a href="#">OTROS SERVICIOS</a>
                    <ul id="subMenuOS">
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#papeleria">PAPELERIA COMERCIAL</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#redes">MANEJO DE REDES</a></li>                           
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#web">DISEÑO WEB</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#estampado">ESTAMPADOS Y BORDADOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#sublimacion">SUBLIMACION</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#pins">PINS PUBLICITARIOS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="otros_servicios.html#impresion">IMPRESION FOTOGRAFICA</a></li>
                        <li><a class="ultimo" href="otros_servicios.html#tarjetas">TARJETAS Y SOUVENIRS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="contacto"><a onClick="displayFormContact('block')">CONTACTO</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

funcion javascript

```
function displayFormContact(status){
var form = document.getElementById("contact_form")
form.style.display = status;


document.getElementById("cardMenu").style.display = "none";  //////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAR LA SECCION*/
}
```

El problema lo tengo con los tamaños mas grandes donde el menu esta desplegado en la parte superior (como siempre suele estar). Cuando selecciono alguna sección esta todo bien, pero al seleccionar el formulario de contactos (que aparece en la misma seccion en la que estoy, sin direccionar a otra seccion) se desaparece el menu por la funcion que tiene (necesaria en tamaños de pantalla chicos)

Como puedo activar o desactivar esta funcion dependiendo del tamaño de pantalla del usuario.

Para ver el menu funcionando y el problema en vivo entrar por favor a

www.graficaelpunto.com/web

gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hice un pequeño código para que puedas guiarte en como puedes detectar el ancho de la ventana y como interactua con varias funciones, aparte hice un evento **resize** para el objeto **window** para que puedas probar cuando cambie de resolución como llama a otras funciones:

```js
var anchoVentana = window.innerWidth

const funcion1 = () => {
  alert("funcion1");
}

const funcion2 = () => {
  alert("funcion2");
}

const funcion3 = () => {
  alert("funcion3");
}

window.onresize = function(){

 anchoVentana = window.innerWidth;
 console.log(anchoVentana)

};

if(anchoVentana > 1000){
  funcion1();
}else if(anchoVentana > 750 && anchoVentana < 1000){
  funcion2();
}else{
  funcion3();
}
```

Si te fijas obtengo el ancho de la ventana con **window.innerWidth**, luego lo evaluo según mi criterio o el tuyo que función llamar, en donde esta los **ifs** ahi colocas o contemplas en que resolución vas a llamar una u otra función.

Answer (score 0):

por si alguien tiene el mismo problema, ahi va como quedo la funcion de javascript.

```
var anchoVentana = window.innerWidth

function displayFormContact(status){

    if(anchoVentana < 600){
        var form = document.getElementById("contact_form")
        form.style.display = status;

        document.getElementById("cardMenu").style.display = "none";  //////////*CIERRA MENU AL SELECCIONAR LA SECCION*/

    } else{
        var form = document.getElementById("contact_form")
        form.style.display = status;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias por la orientación David Molina